# debug php on atom. Вывод строк из файла

Tags: php, отладка

Подскажите пожалуйста дебагер!

Я недавно начал учить php, и пишу в редакторе atom (который посоветовал мне знакомый) – до этого установил себе и пользовался sublime text (когда начал учить html & css). Сейчас же уже немного привык к редактору atom. И в прошлом моем вопросе, мне посоветовали «первым делом при изучении php нужно разобраться как дебажить свои скрипты» @toxxxa. Как я понял, дебагер будет показывать выполнение кода по шагам! Подскажите как это делать на atom.
И еще вопрос – почему ничего не выводится?

---

```
<?php
  $datatxt=file("table.txt");
  $lnarr=count($datatxt);
  for ($i=1; $i <= $lnarr; $i++) {
    $a=$lnarr[$i];
    echo $a;
  }
 ?>
```

---

*table.txt*

```
name surname age
 1
 2
 3
```

---

*P.S: идея кода - сделать таблицу, и поля при заполнении которых инфа идет в txt файл, а после оттуда читается и пишется в таблицу.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы по факту задали два вопроса. Странно что не прикрыли.

Что касается вывода из файла:

```
<?php
  $datatxt=file("table.txt");
  $lnarr=count($datatxt);
  for ($i=1; $i <= $lnarr; $i++) {
    $a=$lnarr[$i]; 
    echo $a;
  }
 ?>
```

**$lnarr** содержит количество элементов массива, который вернула функция [file](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php).

Одна строка - один элемент.

Вы обращаетесь к **$lnarr** как к массиву(хотя это число) и пытаетесь вывести результат, вместо того чтобы выводить данные из **$datatxt**

```
<?php

  $datatxt=file("table.txt");

  $lnarr=count($datatxt);

  for ($i=0; $i < $lnarr; $i++) {

    echo $datatxt[$i];
  }

 ?>
```

Индексы массива нумеруются с 0, в вашем случае вы устанавливаете **$i** = 1 тем самым пропуская первый элемент массива. Т.е начнете со второго.

Из-за знака **=** в цикле вы получите ошибку, так как в конце будете обращаться к несуществующему элементу массива.

Что касается дебага:

Для atom'a есть пакет [php-debug](https://atom.io/packages/php-debug) использующий XDebug

Comment: Спасибо!) Но на счет дебага все равно еще не разобрался(
И как выводить по слову в строке?
Блин вы такие классные))
Хочу себе друга программиста))

Comment: @ALPHA
используйте [explode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php).
Например $str = "слово слово слова"; $arr = explode(" ", $str);
На выходе будет массив и трех улементов.

Comment: Спасибо, я как раз думал о такой функции, только не знал как она называется! ^^